# Display author Post WordPress (Post Edit by Author name)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

Hello WordPress People Good Day!, I hope all are alright Stay home. 
.
.
I need help by the way Is there any way to display author name who edited other author post? 
.
.
For instance author1 PostTitle1,
Then author2 edited PostTitle1 which posted by author1
.
.
The main goals is when the other author edit the post which they are not the owned of the post is there any way to determine who is that author edit that post? 
.
.
For Instance
PostTitle1 Posted by author1 (edited by author2), something like that.
.
Every post that will edit by other authors possible to be determined?
What is WordPress function that I need to know…
Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: You should look into WP’s “revisions” system, https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/revisions/

Comment: In the `posts` table, there is a column `post_author`, that is always the last person that edited the post. The revisions are stored with `post_type=revision`, and `post_parent` set to the ID of the current latest version. So you could get all previous authors that worked on a specific post that way.

Comment: Thank you very much! here's link exactly what I need maybe help us too again someday 
link: wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238105/get-last-revision-author-author-link-and-date